# notepad++ nppftp doesn't reload changed files

Tags: notepad++

I use the nppftp-plugin on a sftp-server. That works fine but when a file on the server is changed directly (or in parallel by someone else), npp does not detect this. A file reload also doesn't read the changed content. I must close the file and open it again to get the new content. And what if I am not aware that the file was changed (for ex another coder is editing php file in parallel)

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're asking FTP to do things it was not made to do.

Comment: I have the same problem!!!! Have you solved this issue???

Comment: GMsoF: check the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative solution would be:

1. using sshfs mounting software for windows ([sftp-net-drive](http://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/index.php) or [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en) or [win-sshfs](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) or similar) mount ssh file system.
2. use notepad++ as if you edit a file localy.

from the list, I prefer [sftp-net-drive](http://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/index.php), it's more compatible with ssh servers and customizable.

---

UPDATE:
Found another app - [RaiDrive](https://www.raidrive.com/)

It works faster and much better than [sftp-net-drive](http://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/index.php).
I am using now [RaiDrive](https://www.raidrive.com/).

Comment: UPDATE: Found another app - RaiDrive
It works faster and much better than sftp-net-drive. I am using now RaiDrive.

Answer (score 1):

No NPPFTP can not synchronize its not designed for that but u can surely write a script to copy all file from FTP to local machine after each time you do editing with some different tools that will help.